# Fetching images from database on the selection of item in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to ASP.NET MVC and don't know much about it. I want to fetch 3 images from the database on the selection of item from the list and display on the webpage. I set the Id for the list box items and primary key of the table same. here is the code what I have tried yet, but its not working what modification should I made. (URl of the images are stored in database)

Model Class:

```
public class UserDetailModel
{
    public string LetterId { get; set; }
    public string LetterPic { get; set; }
    public string LetterRecord { get; set; }
    public string LetterWord { get; set; }
    public string LetterWord_Pic { get; set; }
    public string LetterWordRecord { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "LetterDetail")]
    public List<LetterList> letterDetail;
    [Display(Name = "selectedLetter")]
    public string selectedLetter { get; set; }
}

public class LetterList
{
    public string listId { get; set; }
    public string listName { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult letter(string SelectedLetter)
 {   
     demo.Models.UserDetailModel obj = new demo.Models.UserDetailModel();
     obj.letterDetail = new List<LetterList>()
         {
             new LetterList() { listId = "1", listName =  "A" },
             new LetterList() { listId = "2",  listName= "B" },
             new LetterList() { listId = "3",  listName= "C" },
             new LetterList() { listId ="4",  listName= "D"}
         };
    return View(obj);

    using (var context = new VirtualSpeechTherapistEntities())
    {
         var hurf = from b in context.hurf_e_tahaji
                    where b.Letter_Id = SelectedLetter 
                    select b;
         return View("letter", context);
   };
```

Primary key should be equal to selected listItem id , what to write in where clause ?//

View:

```
@model demo.Models.UserDetailModel

@Html.ListBoxFor(obj => obj.selectedLetter, new SelectList (Model.letterDetail, "listId","listName")) ;

@Html.Id(Model.selectedLetter);

<img src="@Url.Content(Model.LetterPic)"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be helpful to include the error message you get when trying to run the code.

However, first off, where you are calling the LetterPic Url:

```
<img src="@Url.Content(Model.LetterPic)"/>
```

In your controller, you are never assigning a value to the obj.LetterPic. Nor do you pull the UserDetailModel from the database. Instead, you are creating a new UserDetailModel, which means all of the values are starting out blank.

You might try to assign a value to the obj.LetterPic in your controller, before returning it to the view and see if that solves your problem.

It is also important to note, the second part of your controller, everything after "return View(obj);" does not ever run in your controller. If you need the VirtualSpeechTherapistEntities part to run, it needs to be done before you do a return.